# 'Wildcard' for checking captured log outputs using Python's testfixtures module

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing some unit tests for a server program which catches most exceptions, but logs them, and would like to make assertions on the logged output. I've found the [testfixtures](https://github.com/Simplistix/testfixtures) package useful to this end; for example:

```
import logging
import testfixtures

with testfixtures.LogCapture() as l:
    logging.info('Here is some info.')

l.check(('root', 'INFO', 'Here is some info.'))
```

Following the [documentation](http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html#the-context-manager), the `check` method will raise an error if either the logger name, level, or message is not as expected.

I would like to perform a more 'flexible' kind of test in which I make assertions on the message using a wildcard for the other elements of the tuple. This less stringent assertion would look something like

```
l.check((*, *, 'Here is some info.'))
```

but this is not valid syntax. Is there any way to specify a 'wildcard' in the `check` method of the `testfixtures.logcapture.LogCapture` class?

Comment: Incidentally, in Python 3 there is also the [assertLogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs) method, of which the `output` appears to be a string consisting of the same tuple (logger name, level, and message) concatenated with colons (`:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to check messages only (which, as pointed out to me by the author, is actually described in the [documentation](http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html#inspecting)) is to use the `records` attribute of the `LogCapture` class, which is a list of [logging.LogRecord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) objects. So the appropriate assertion is:

```
assert l.records[-1].getMessage() == 'Here is some info.'
```

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the `attributes` parameter as documented here: http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#testfixtures.LogCapture

Comment: I also hate asserts, would always recommend compare instead: http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing.html#the-compare-function